# NSNumber class does not respond to initWithFloat: method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to get NSNumber to respond to the initWithFloat method, but my program is responding with an "NSNumber may not respond to initWithFloat method" and is not returning the right result.

Here is the code:

```
#import "VariableTestAppDelegate.h"

@implementation VariableTestAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{ 
    NSNumber *myNumber;
    myNumber = [NSNumber initWithFloat:3.47];
    NSLog(@"The value in NSNumber is %@", myNumber);
}
@end
```

The error message which gets sent to the console reads:

```
2011-03-12 09:00:08.569 VariableTest[6228:a0f] +[NSNumber initWithFloat:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7fff70bfd808
2011-03-12 09:00:08.572 VariableTest[6228:a0f] +[NSNumber initWithFloat:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7fff70bfd808
```

What is the problem? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-initWithFloat:` is not a class method.  You need to create an instance first and then send it `-initWithFloat:`.

```
myNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat: 34.7];
```

Or you can use the convenience method

```
myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 34.7];
```

This second case gives you an `NSNumber` that you do not own.  If you want to keep it around you need to retain it.

Answer (score 1):

`initWithFloat:` is an *instance method* which you are trying to call on a class, to create a new autoreleased `NSNumber` instance use the *class method* [`numberWithFloat:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000178-numberWithFloat_).

```
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.47];
```

Answer (score 1):

`-init` and `-initWith...:` are instance methods, not class methods. You should send `alloc` to the class to create a new instance, and then send an initialization message.

```
[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat: 12.0f]
```

Sometimes classes define convenience constructors, which allocate an autoreleased object and initialize it in the same method. Thus:

```
[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 12.0f]
```

However these will never begin with init.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class method and then retain it. You must then release it later.

```
NSNumber *aNumber = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.14] retain];
```